# print first column and print everything after % sign

Tags: sed, awk

I want to print the first column in this case the host IP and everything after `%` character.

> 10.162.254.12 3558: 003557: Mar 4 2013 12:13:28: %LINEPROTO-SP-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface
>   GigabitEthernet8/37, changed state to up 
>   192.50.0.14 : 2013 Mar 4 13:14:20 EST: %ETHPORT-5-IF_DOWN_LINK_FAILURE: Interface Ethernet17/33 is down (Link
>   failure)

Answer (score 2):

You have two `%` characters and didn't specify if everything after the first or last should be printed? Here is both ways using `sed`:

```
# First field and everything after first %
$ sed 's/ [^%]*%/ /' file
10.162.254.12 LINEPROTO-SP-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet8/37, changed state to up 192.50.0.14 : 2013 Mar 4 13:14:20 EST: %ETHPORT-5-IF_DOWN_LINK_FAILURE: Interface Ethernet17/33 is down (Link failure)

# First field and everything after last % 
$ sed 's/ .*%/ /' file
10.162.254.12 ETHPORT-5-IF_DOWN_LINK_FAILURE: Interface Ethernet17/33 is down (Link failure)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\)[^%]*%/\1 /' input
```